# Optimize short part of a SQL Server query

Tags: sql-server, min, isnull

I have this subquery that takes a little to long. Does anyone has any idea about how can I modify it in order to be faster?

```
  ISNULL(ISNULL(
(select top 1 CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), qq.startdate , 111) 
 from (select a.startdate, a.ownerid 
       from wfassignment a
       where a.ownertable='PM' /*order by a.startdate*/)qq 
 where qq.ownerid=pm.pmuid ),
(select min(w.reportdate) 
from workorder w where w.pmnum=pm.pmnum 
                 and w.siteid=pm.siteid 
                 and w.orgid= pm.orgid)
),CONVERT(DATETIME,'01-02-2015 00:00:00'))
```

In oracle it's much more faster than in SQL Server. I also want to know for sure if top 1 is equivalent with rownum=1 from oracle.
Thanks :)

Comment: questions seeking performance help,should  include details like execution plan,schema of tables involved and repro to test :https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/914288/how-to-generate-a-script-of-the-necessary-database-metadata-to-create-a-statistics-only-database-in-sql-server

Comment: Multiple requirements may end up producing queries with identical structures - rather than expecting is to *intuit* the intent behind this query, could you perhaps *explain it*. Sample data and expected results would help a lot.

Comment: It's not faster in Oracle. It's a completely different query, on a completely different database, with different indexes. The query's textual shape doesn't matter if the indexes are different.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need the minimum startdate in your first subquery, so I worked out this:

```
    select   top 1 [sq].[pm_date]
    from
    (
        select  convert(tinyint, 1) as [priority]
              , min(a.startdate) as [pm_date]
        from    wfassignment a
        where   a.ownertable = 'PM'
                and a.ownerid = pm.pmuid

        union all

        select  2
              , min(w.reportdate)
        from    workorder w
        where   w.pmnum = pm.pmnum
                and w.siteid = pm.siteid
                and w.orgid = pm.orgid

        union all

        select  3
              , convert(datetime, '2015-02-01 00:00:00') 
              /* use yyyymmdd format to avoid confusion when casting datetime values */
    ) as sq
    where    [sq].[pm_date] is not null
    order by [sq].[priority] asc
```

You need to add the outer reference to the [pm] alias though, but that part wasn't given in your question, so I've just worked it out like this.